# HLOOKUP & SUM functions in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

working with the below data frame and would like to do a `HLOOKUP()` & `SUM()` like below:

[image]

Ideally, what I would like to get is 67 as a result, based on the search of "A" and summing the corresponding values (`50+17`) in this case.

Here is my syntax, mind telling me if anything I have done wrong here? Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `HLOOKUP()` can;t be done using `SUMIF()` ? Try: `=SUMIF(A2:A5,D1,B2:B5)` or a `SUM()` --> `=SUM(B2:B5*(D1=A2:A5))`

Comment: 1. It would be VLOOKUP not HLOOKUP. 2. Both would only return the first match not all, so neither is the formula you want.  As @MayukhBhattacharya stated, this is a job for SUMIF().

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks it works perfectly with sumif function now, million thanks for your help.